# Android PCM drawing

Tags: android, audio, pcm

i'm trying to draw audio amplitudes by time, i'm using to achieve this, the AudioRecord class, which gives me a raw audio array.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (mIsRecording) {

                int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);

                for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                    long time = mChronometer.getTimeElapsed();
                    ampArray.add((mBuffer[i]));
                    timeArray.add(time);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The parameters i use for AudioRecored are:

```
public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;

 private void initRecorder() {
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
}
```

The result i get is this one:

[The result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMuhU.png)  -----
[What i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioIQt.png)

Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Drawing method:
When the recording is stopped, i send all the values saved in the amplitude array and the one in the time array to the LineGraphSeries of the [GraphView Api](http://www.android-graphview.org/)

```
series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(generateData(ampArray, timeArray));
graph.addSeries(series);
```

generateData method:

```
double x = 0; int i = 0; short y = 0;
private DataPoint[] generateData(ArrayList<Short> ampArray, ArrayList<Double> timeArray) {
    DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[ampArray.size()];

    for (int i=0; i< ampArray.size(); i++) {
        x = timeArray.get(i);
        y = ampArray.get(i);
        DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
        values[i] = v;
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: possibly your code is working or at least in the ballpark  ... try using a simple sine signal as input which is easy to visually verify as OK or not ... perhaps the input you are using has a very great difference between silence and max amplitude and to get the plotting to match up would require doing some log of your signal

Comment: I think i have to review how the audio values are presented

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an educated guess here and suggest that it has something to do with these two lines:

```
long time = mChronometer.getTimeElapsed();
timeArray.add(time);
```

It looks to me like you are trying to plot the samples which have occurred in a different time regime and you are processing in batch against the current CPU clock which would explain your results - for example you might process a big block of samples - which you can do much faster than they occurred in the first place - and they might all get a similar time axis value.

The proper approach is to reconstruct the time axis for the samples themselves. Assume the first sample you process is time 0. If your sample rate is 48000 then each sample is 1/48000 of a second. The approach would be something like this:

```
int sampleNumber = 0;
while (mIsRecording) {

            int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                ampArray.add((mBuffer[i]));
                double time = sampleNumber / SAMPLE_RATE;
                timeArray.add(time);
                sampleNumber++;
            }
        }
```

Note, I changed timeArray from int to double as it is now in seconds rather than milliseconds.  If you prefer milliseconds then multiply time by 1000 and cast to a long.

Also, you don't *need* to create an array for the time axis as you can determine the time of any sample based upon its absolute index in the ampArray.

Comment: Thaks jacket for the answer, the result i get with your midification is weird: http://i.imgur.com/OglONsY.png
The sample rate i use is 8000.

Comment: Why don't you post the drawing procedure you are using in your question.

Comment: I added the method to the first post, Jaket i don't think the problem is coming from the drawing because i used several plotting APIs the result was the same.